# Slightly different memorylessness of exponential distribution

Tags: exponential-distribution

I'm stuck on an exercise, which goes as follows:
Let $ X $ be an exponentially distributed random variable. Show that
\begin{equation}
P(X\leq s+t\mid X>s)=P(X\leq t)
\end{equation}
for all $ s,t\geq0 $.

I know that $ P(X\leq s+t|X>s)=\frac{P((X\leq s+t)\cap(X>s))}{P(X>s)} $. But I don't know how to further rearrange the numerator.

I have seen proofs for a similar equation, but never for this one. Can someone help me or give a hint, how I could show this?

Comment: What happens if you subtract both sides from $1$?

Comment: Well, $ 1-P(X\leq t)=P(X>t) $. I'm not sure about the other side, though. Can I just do a proof by contradiction and suppose, that $ P(X\leq s+t|X>s)=P(X>t) $?

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(\cdot \mid X>s)$ is another probability law, so this enjoys all the property that $\mathbb{P}(\cdot)$ has. For instance, you still have $$1-\mathbb{P}(X\leq s+t\mid X>s)=\mathbb{P}(X>s+t\mid X>s).$$ Also, I am not sure about what you mean by 'proof by contradiction'. If you want to employ that proof technique, you will need to derive a contradiction from the assumption $$\mathbb{P}(X\leq s+t\mid X>s)\neq\mathbb{P}(X\leq t),$$ and I see no obvious (and non-redundant) way to do so.